# ADO CommandText syntax

Tags: c#, string

Does anyone know why sometimes an `@` is used preceding a commandText string?

both seem to work fine.

```
command.CommandText = @"SELECT id FROM users";
```

or

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM users";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is C#'s verbatim string literal notation.

A verbatim string literal is preceded by a leading **`@`** and anything between the quotes that follow that **`@`** will be considered part of the string literal without any need for escaping.

Please see [String literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(VS.71).aspx):

> C# supports two forms of string
>   literals: regular string literals and
>   verbatim string literals.
>
> A regular string literal consists of
>   zero or more characters enclosed in
>   double quotes, as in "hello", and may
>   include both simple escape sequences
>   (such as \t for the tab character) and
>   hexadecimal and Unicode escape
>   sequences.
>
> ***A verbatim string literal consists of
>   an @ character followed by a
>   double-quote character, zero or more
>   characters, and a closing double-quote
>   character. A simple example is
>   `@"hello"`. In a verbatim string
>   literal, the characters between the
>   delimiters are interpreted verbatim,
>   the only exception being a
>   quote-escape-sequence. In particular,
>   simple escape sequences and
>   hexadecimal and Unicode escape
>   sequences are not processed in
>   verbatim string literals. A verbatim
>   string literal may span multiple
>   lines.***

Most likely a query was spanning multiple lines and whomever wrote the code wanted to put it on multiple lines like this:

```
command.CommandText = @"SELECT id
                       FROM users";
```

Whereas without a verbatim string literal you would have to do this:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT id"
                      + " FROM users";
```

Answer (score 0):

& = ampersand
@ = at (or at the rate of)

Answer (score 0):

@ is the verbatim string operator. It comes in really handy when dealing with regular expressions. If you're looking for white space characters, you can specify

```
new RegEx( @"[\w]+")
```

instead of

```
new RegEx("[\\w]+")
```

to escape the '\'. The example works better for more complicated regular expressions.